# Can't rename file if extension has 4 characters

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I need to rename a file from my C++ program, so I use rename(), which should be part of the standard ([see cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/rename/)).

On Linux it works fine, but on Windows 64 bits the rename() call fails. The rename() call does not like having a source file with 4 characters in its extension.

Here's the combination and its effects:

1) 4 characters in the source extension:

```
const int ret = rename("test.toml", "renamed.toml");
```

Then ret == -1 and no rename.

2) 3 characters in the source extension, 4 in the destination:

```
const int ret = rename("test.tom", "renamed.toml");
```

Then ret == 0 and the rename succeeds.

3) 3 characters everywhere:

```
const int ret = rename("test.tom", "renamed.tom");
```

Then ret == 0 and the rename succeeds.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw5t957f.aspx), the list of possible return values is given [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3ayayh1.aspx) and it does not include "-1"...

I switched to cstdio's rename() because I had similar issue with boost: using boost:filesystem::rename() was throwing an exception that I've never been able to diagnose...

Any idea as to what might be causing this?? I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Express Update 3 (v11.00.60610.1) on Windows 64 bits. Thanks.

Comment: When the function fails, you should really check the error, you can do that by checking [`errno`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/errno), or print it out using [`std::perror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/perror).

Comment: For anyone wondering, Windows [does not have a cap](http://superuser.com/a/315395/124696).

Comment: I can't re-create this behavior on a windows machine (though I did compile with GNU), are you sure the source file exists?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: yes, I'm checking the error code. Thanks for the hint on perror. Unfortunately, I get "unknown error" as the source of error!

Comment: Attach a debugger and debug.  We ship the CRT sources with Visual Studio, to allow you to debug through them.  I cannot repro this problem on Windows 8.  Note that the documentation is correct.  It states "on an error, the function returns a nonzero value and sets errno."  -1 is a nonzero value.

Comment: From your cplusplus link: On failure, a nonzero value is returned. This includes -1 which you seem to be confused about

Comment: @JamesMcNellis & networkburner: I am checking for a non-zero return value. I get -1 which, yes, is non-zero, but strerror() returns "Unknown error". I'll continue debugging this...

Comment: @Keyser As far as I can tell, modern Windows has adopted the Unix convention: the filename is just text, and you can have names like `"a.b..c"`, and actually use it as a C source code file.  (A lot of applications _do_ have conventions.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Even better. I myself have no idea how Windows treats extensions nowadays. I haven't used Windows since XP (when extensions defaulted to hidden, and the operating system flipped out if there was something odd with them)

Comment: @big_gie - `rename` is just a wrapper around `MoveFileEx` that maps its error codes to `errno`.  Try calling `MoveFileEx` directly then calling `GetLastError` to get the raw error code from Windows.  That should give you more information.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365240(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @shf301 I tried MoveFileEx(); its return code was 32, and according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx it's an "ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION" (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.) The file in question is an input file, so it's probably still opened and blocked. $%?$? windows... I just tried renaming a different file and don't have issue with the extension...